# Is there a function to create a loop to replace data?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mailmerge

I created this function (using a youtube tutorial) to send grades to parents in my school.
So the result is the following:

```
20-10-13 12:16:57:353 CDT] Entrega de Calificaciones 
Buen dia:

Por medio de la presente le informamos que su hijo(a) (STUDENT NAME)
que cursa el grado de Secundaria 1° A obtuvo las siguientes calificaciones
en el 1er. parcial:

ESPAÑOL (8.3) 
HISTORIA 6.2 
FCyE 6.8 
ARTISTICAS 10.0 
MATEMÁTICAS 7,7 
BIOLOGÍA 9.5 
COMPUTACIÓN 8.5 
INGLÉS 6.2 
GEOGRAFÍA 1.4
```

I had to create a template to do that. My intention is to replace the name of the student in a given row, and replace the grades of that student which are in the same row without changing the constants and send a personalized email to each parent

i don't know if it is possible, and how would it work.

Thank you in advance

This is the code:

```
function enviarMail(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("1A");
  var plantilla = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("1A").getRange("B1").getValue()
  var range = ss.getRange(6, 1, 28, 13)
  
  var email = ss.getRange("b6").getValue();
  var nombre = ss.getRange("d6").getValue();
  const grupo = ss.getRange("d2").getValue();
  const periodo = ss.getRange("d4").getValue();
  const esp = ss.getRange("e1").getValue();var espres = ss.getRange("e6").getValue();var espres2 = ss.getRange("s6").getValue();
  const hist = ss.getRange("f1").getValue();var histres = ss.getRange("f6").getValue();var histres2 = ss.getRange("t6").getValue();
  const fce = ss.getRange("g1").getValue();var fceres = ss.getRange("g6").getValue();var fceres2 = ss.getRange("u6").getValue();
  const art = ss.getRange("h1").getValue();var artres = ss.getRange("h6").getValue();var artres2 = ss.getRange("v6").getValue();
  const mat = ss.getRange("i1").getValue();var matres = ss.getRange("i6").getValue();var matres2 = ss.getRange("w6").getValue();
  const bio = ss.getRange("j1").getValue();var biores = ss.getRange("j6").getValue();var biores2 = ss.getRange("x6").getValue();
  const com = ss.getRange("k1").getValue();var comres = ss.getRange("k6").getValue();var comres2 = ss.getRange("y6").getValue();
  const ing = ss.getRange("l1").getValue();var ingres = ss.getRange("l6").getValue();var ingres2 = ss.getRange("z6").getValue();
  const geo = ss.getRange("m1").getValue();var geores = ss.getRange("m6").getValue();var geores2 = ss.getRange("aa6").getValue();
  
  
  var asunto = "Entrega de Calificaciones"
  var mensaje = plantilla .replace("{nombre}",nombre).replace("{grupo}",grupo).replace("{periodo}",periodo)
  .replace("{esp}", esp).replace("{espres}",espres).replace("{espres2}",espres2)
  .replace("{hist}", hist).replace("{histres}",histres).replace("{histres2}",histres2)
  .replace("{fce}", fce).replace("{fceres}",fceres).replace("{fceres2}",fceres2)
  .replace("{art}", art).replace("{artres}",artres).replace("{artres2}",artres2)
  .replace("{mat}", mat).replace("{matres}",matres).replace("{matres2}",matres2)
  .replace("{bio}", bio).replace("{biores}",biores).replace("{biores2}",biores2)
  .replace("{com}", com).replace("{comres}",comres).replace("{comres2}",comres2)
  .replace("{ing}", ing).replace("{ingres}",ingres).replace("{ingres2}",ingres2)
  .replace("{geo}", geo).replace("{geores}",geores).replace("{geores2}",geores2)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. What are you looking for is a feature that is commonly known as "mail merge". Using this name you could find a lot of examples, actually the Google Apps Script site includes several examples, here is one of them https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge

Comment: Question in this site should be *more* specific. I suggest you to read the refererred article and if you get stuck, edit the question to make it more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I have a soft spot for teachers and I actually had some code that sort of does exactly what you're trying to do. I cleaned it up a little to match your situation. If you explore with it a little you might be able to make some progress.

You can see my [example here and make your own copy.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19EtEO4YNaio8JvUEmTmn5Ff3whJ1g3BSHVNhwSvFiLU/edit#gid=0)

The spreadsheet assumes you have your kids' grade in some table format (in my case columns `Q:S`). Then all of the students are listed in Column G along with a corresponding email, greeting, subject, their grades (string together as array) and then a closing. The hardest part is probably the excel array function, but all of this is regular spreadsheet functionality.

The process that runs this is shown below. It loops down Column G until it hits a blank row. Note that if you want to exclude members, uncheck them in F.

```
const ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("1A");
const firstCellofNames = "G2";
const columnWithMessage = "M";



function runProcess() {  
  var theKid = ss.getRange(firstCellofNames);
  while(!theKid.isBlank()){
   
    if(theKid.offset(0,-1).getValue()===true){
      sendEmail(theKid.getA1Notation());
    } 
    theKid = theKid.offset(1,0);
  }      
}

function sendEmail(theAddress){
  var thePerson = ss.getRange(theAddress)
  var theEmailAddress = thePerson.offset(0,1).getValue();
  var theSubject = thePerson.offset(0,2).getValue();
  var theMessage = ss.getRange(columnWithMessage + thePerson.getRow()).getValue()
    
  var newEmail = GmailApp.createDraft(theEmailAddress, theSubject, theMessage)
  newEmail.send();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have the following Apps Script function performing the following (the code is explained through the comments within):

```js
// A function is a piece of code that executes some functionallity such as sending an email
function enviarMail(){
// Here you are getting the sheet that you are working in
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("1A");
// Get the value of cell B1
  var plantilla = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("1A").getRange("B1").getValue();
  
  // Get the values of the range of cells from A6 to AB14
  var range = ss.getRange(6, 1, 28, 13);

// Get the value that is in the cell B6 (and you basically get the rest of the values using the same mechanism)
  var email = ss.getRange("b6").getValue();
  var nombre = ss.getRange("d6").getValue();
  // Then you do the same for an amount of cells...

  //Set a subject to a variable
  var asunto = "Entrega de Calificaciones";
  
  // Create a message for the email using the values we obtained from the previous methods where we were getting these values from different cells of the spreadsheet
  // In this message you are replacing a string (text) for the values in your cells. For example if you have "Soy nombre" and in your Spreadsheet you have Juan then you are substituying "nombre" with "Juan" -> "Soy Juan"
  var mensaje = plantilla .replace("{nombre}",nombre).replace("{grupo}",grupo).replace("{periodo}",periodo)
  .replace("{esp}", esp).replace("{espres}",espres).replace("{espres2}",espres2)
//...do the same operation for all the values
}
```

This function just gets the details of a single student as it gets the values on a single row. If you want to send emails to all the students you will have to get the rest of the cells.

This can be easily achieved with a [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) where you iterate over all the rows of the students, get their values and send an email to each of them.

To get all the marks and details of each student you could instead of getting their separate cell values, get all the student values for their names, grades, etc in arrays using `getValues()` and then iterate over a for loop to send an email for each.

To exemplify this, here is an example on how to do this just with their names. For doing it also with their grades and the rest just follow the same principles done with their names:

```js
//Get all the names considering they start from row 6 and that they are in column 4 (D)
// As getValues() return a 2D array I am flattening it into a 1D array so that we only
// need to go through a single for loop iteration. 
// NOTE : (start at row 6, start at column 4, get the last row with content and
// substract the rows we ommitted in the beggining to get the total number of rows and
// set the number of columns to just one. 
var nombres = ss.getRange(6, 4,ss.getLastRow()-5,1).getValues().flat();

// Go over each name of the array
  for(i=0;i<emails.length;i++){
 // set the name and replace it for the name in the template
    nombre =  nombres[i];
    var asunto = "Entrega de Calificaciones";
    var mensaje = plantilla .replace("{nombre}",nombre)
    }
}
```

I would recommend you go over [Apps Script guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) and read through to understand better what these two pieces of code are doing.

#### References

[getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)

[getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

[replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

[SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)

Comment: I appreciate your time for answering my request, i am pretty sure this may help me a lot to solve my problem. 
Unfortunately, i don't know anything about Codes, everything i did was based on a youtube video, and your answer is Chinese for me. =(
Would you be willing to see my original file to see what i did and then my script again?

I know this is a lot to ask. 

Here it is:

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DSiZ5a279ceLZq8VQnkp_aWQogA4Pfv2kq4-sYpY-to/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi ! I cannot code an answer for you as that does not follow Stack Overflow guidelines, please check [How to Aks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Before using any piece of code you might want to read a bit about it and invest some time on the [Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) to learn how to use it accordingly. I also have editted my answer to clarify better what I meant and included some relevant references for someone with an entry level. Hope that helps and solves your problem :D